# PDO lastInsertid() is returning false, even though my query is running fine. Giving 0000 code error

Tags: php, pdo

Here is my code, i am tryng to insert data into database using PDO, i don't know where my code went wrong that is not inserting and returning false on lastInsertId(). Have a look at my code:

Model.php

```
<?php
abstract class Model{
protected $dbh;
protected $stmt;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
     }

     public function error(){
        print_r($this->dbh->errorInfo());
     }

     public function query($query){
       $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
     }

    //Binds the prep statement
    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
      if (is_null($type)) {
          switch (true) {
              case is_int($value):
                  $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                  break;
              case is_bool($value):
                  $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                  break;
              case is_null($value):
                  $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                  break;
              default:
                  $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
       }
      }
      $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
  }

   public function execute(){
      return $this->stmt->execute();
   }

    public function resultset(){
       $this->execute();
       return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function lastInsertId(){
        return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
    }

    public function single(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    }
```

register function:(this is my register function where insert query is).

```
public function register(){

    $post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $pass = md5($post['password']);
    if(isset($post['submit']))
    {
        $this->query('INSERT INTO tbl_users (firstname, lastname, email, password, gender, dob) VALUES(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, :gender, :dob)');
        $this->bind('firstname', $post['fname']);
        $this->bind('lastname', $post['lname']);
        $this->bind('email', $post['email']);
        $this->bind('password', $pass);
        $this->bind('gender', $post['gender']);
        $this->bind('dob', $post['date']);
        $this->execute();

        if($this->lastInsertId()){
            header('Location:'.ROOT_PATH.'admin/user');
        }else{
            echo "wrong";
            $this->error();
        }
    }
}
```

Can Somebody tell me where i did wrong, and why this is happening, Any help would be appreciated. Thank You in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `$this->lastInsertId()`? Zero?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte it is resolved now. Thanks for participating. check my answer if you would want to know how.

Comment: Why did you names you PDO wrapped as "Model"? Why are you using MD5 for hashing password? Why have you not looked up how to correctly set up PDO connection?

Comment: @tereško i am just learning, tell me how can i improve my code?

Comment: @GurpreetKaur most important part: use https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.password.php for hashing/verifying passwords. MD5 is **NOT** secure, because it was designed for speed. As for "model" part, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864000/727208) might help. And regarding PDO setup: read http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: @tereško Thank You for your guidance. I will surely improve my code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved. It was one of my database fields causing the issue. I set NULL equals to no and also wasn't giving any default value, which caused the error. I found out about it by replacing my code in model.php:

```
$this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```

with this:

```
$options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
$this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $options);
```